# Converting the value in specific date format into another specified format in u-sql script using u-sql operators and functions

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, u-sql

lets say i have two variables a and b declared in the u-sql script as mentioned below. I have a scenario where i need to check the datetime value of column in a specific table is ranging in between two datetime values which are declared as variables below.

sample value of STARTDATETIME Column: 2018-11-06T14:06:15.0000000

I am able to convert time1 as it is straight forward and but i am not able to convert time2 which is in format ending with Z to StartDateTime Format .Can Someone help me on how i can do this Conversion Correctly in U-SQL Script

U-SQL Script:

```
DECLARE @time1 string = "11/11/2018 12:34:12 AM";

DECLARE @time2 string = "2018-11-11T06:46:52.3143918Z";

//sql query snippet in u-sql script

@testfile = SELECT [PRODUCT],[STARTDATETIME] from TABLEA WHERE [STARTDATETIME] BETWEEN Convert.ToDateTime(@time1) AND ?????
```

Comment: Try with DateTime.Parse(@time2) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
@testfile = SELECT [PRODUCT],[STARTDATETIME] from TABLEA WHERE [STARTDATETIME] BETWEEN Convert.ToDateTime(@time1) AND DateTime.ParseExact(@time2, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ", NULL);
```